# Magento 2.3.4 breadcrumb not showing full path

Tags: magento2.3.4

I want to show the category name in the URL of the product page and breadcrumb but it's not working as per expectation.

It should be like **Home > category name > product name**
but it showing like **Home > product name**

I have updated "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" still no change in breadcrumb or URL.

Is it possible for an admin to do the changes or do I need to add a custom block?

Answer (score 0):

Magento by default provides this functionality.

When you navigate to any product using navigation(using category) it will by default show full breadcrumbs on the product page.

It will not show full breadcrumbs if you directly navigate to the product using a URL.

Comment: Full breadcrumb not showing anyways, can you have a look here - https://testing.kratomcountry.com/